# DJANGO: Need help in implementation of price filtering of items through HTML <FORM>

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

I wanted to add buttons to select between ASC or DSC order of viewing items.
I added a radio button to select between ascending order of price and descending order of price of items to be shown. I know how to sort the list of the hat items in descending or ascending order in views.py but I don't know what condition to use and how to change the order through the form in the html code. I'm new to this and this is my first project in DJANGO. I know I have to get some POST input through the form and use that variable in the condition in views.py but I don't know how.
Thankyou.

relevant part of views.py file:

```
def head_wear(request):
    if(#whatconditionhere):

        hat_list=models.Hat.objects.order_by('price')
    else:
        hat_list = models.Hat.objects.order_by('-price')

    stuff_for_frontend = {
        'hat_list': hat_list,

    }
    return render(request, 'AUM/head_wear.html',stuff_for_frontend)
```

relevant part of head_wear.html

```
  <form class="form-inline" action="#">
      <div class="col s4 offset-s4">
    <p>
      <label>
        <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" checked />
        <span style="color:white;">Ascending</span>
      </label>
    </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col s4 offset-s4">
    <p>
      <label style="padding-left:150%;">
        <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" />
        <span style="color:white;">Descending</span>
      </label>
    </p>
      </div>



  </form>
```

urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('head_wear',views.head_wear,name='head_wear'),
    path('shirt_wear',views.shirt_wear,name='shirt_wear'),
    path('pant_wear',views.pant_wear,name='pant_wear'),
    path('watch_wear',views.watch_wear,name='watch_wear'),
    path('shoe_wear',views.shoe_wear,name='shoe_wear'),

    ]
```

Complete head_wear.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<style>

[type="radio"]:checked + span:after,

[type="radio"].with-gap:checked + span:before,

[type="radio"].with-gap:checked + span:after {

  border: 2px solid #8003fc;

}



[type="radio"]:checked + span:after,

[type="radio"].with-gap:checked + span:after {

  background-color: #8003fc;

}
.card {
    height: 400px; /* Your height here */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card-image {
    height: 250px; /* Your height here */
    overflow: hidden;
}


</style>
<h2 style="color:white;text-align:center;">Head Wear - By AUM</h2>
<div class="row" style="background-color:#8003fc;color:#8003fc">g</div>
<div class="container">
        <h6 style="color:white;text-align:center">Price</h6>


  <form class="form-inline" action="#">
      <div class="col s4 offset-s4">
    <p>
      <label>
        <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" checked />
        <span style="color:white;">Ascending</span>
      </label>
    </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col s4 offset-s4">
    <p>
      <label style="padding-left:150%;">
        <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" />
        <span style="color:white;">Descending</span>
      </label>
    </p>
      </div>



  </form>



<div class="row">
    {% for hat in hat_list %}

  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col s4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="{{hat.image}}">
          <span class="card-title"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>{{hat.name}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a href="/">View Item. Price: ${{hat.price}}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


    {%endfor%}
</div>

</div>


{%endblock content%}
```

Comment: Hi , you can use `onchange` event on your radio button so whenever you change value of radio button call your ajax and pass the checked value to backend and depending on this return relevant `json` or `html view` to construct your `rows`.

Comment: Im sorry but what's an ajax?